# How to load bitmapsource from file with the correct orientation in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: test.jpg]

The above image is 480x720 in pixels. It came from a vertical shoot of a Canon DSLC. Windows can show it in the right way, same as StackOverflow do.

However, the following code does not:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.StreamSource = File.OpenRead("test.jpg");
bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmap.EndInit();

//Fail; bitmap.PixelWidth==720
Debug.Assert(bitmap.PixelWidth==480);
//Fail; bitmap.PixelHeight==480
Debug.Assert(bitmap.PixelWidth==720);
```

So how can I get it in the right way within WPF in C#?

Comment: Technically, this is not a duplication - the linked question is about reading EXIF using GDI+ (`System.Drawing.Bitmap` stuff) but I am using WPF.

Comment: It's all the same though- the way to get the orientation (by which you would rotate the image) is outlined in that question.

Comment: @Chris I don't think this question is duplicate because he asked the way in WPF and in WPF, System.Windows.Media.Imaging will be the first choice rather than System.Drawing.

Comment: @Earth I checked your image by System.Windows.Media.Imaging but it seems not to contain Exif orientation data. And I think the last line in your code should be "Debug.Assert(bitmap.PixelHeight==720);"